# java webstart deployment toolkit detection fails

Tags: java, java-web-start

I just tried the JWS deployment toolkit as desribed here: http://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/deployment_toolkit_101 
I want to use it to launch an application (not an applet). But the JRE detection fails completely. I tried it in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer but it always redirects me to the Java download site. But I definitely have Java installed:

```
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

I also tried it on a 32bit Windows XP in a VM with the same result, java version there is:

```
java version "1.6.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_07-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 10.0-b23, mixed mode, sharing)
```

When I directly call the `getJREs` function of the deployment toolkit it returns nothing.

I'd appreciate any advice on how to make this work.

Comment: Check [Java Web Start - Runtime Versioning](http://pscode.org/jws/version.html) carefully for tips.

Comment: The jnlp runtime versioning happens at a later time in the process than described here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have dropped all attempts to autodetect if Java is installed or not in the browser page.  Simply provide a Java WebStart link, and have a note below saying essentially "If the link doesn't work, *get Java here*" and then link to the appropriate detection page on java.com.

I would suggest you do the same.

Comment: Remember that for best operation, the web server should use the MIME type "application/x-java-jnlp-file JNLP" for the jnlp-file.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works perfectly like this:

```
<html>
...
<head>
...
<script src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
...

To run the app click on the button: 
<script language="JavaScript">

deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton('http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/examples/webstart_ComponentArch_DynamicTreeDemo/src/dynamictree-webstart.jnlp', '1.6.0');

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**The bad thing is, if javascript is turned off, the button won't show.**

Then you have to do a mime check for: "application/x-java-jnlp-file"